# Cannot perform javascript function and met "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable, datatables

I have the error which is "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" in my 'Create.aspx', and the following is my code and I have import the jscript file. Is it the jscript version different with my project or the software?

*Note:
-Software used: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
-Project: ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application(ASPX C#)
-Error Line: **Bold Sentences** And **

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcPOS.Models.Sales>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2 class="h2"> <%: (string)ViewBag.Title%> </h2>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" >

**function DeleteRow() {
    // Here I have used DataTables.TableTools plugin for getting selected row items
    var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance('tbl'); // Get Table instance
    var sRow = oTT.fnGetSelected(); // Get Selected Item From Table
    // Set deleted row item to editable text boxes
    $('#ItemSalesID').val($.trim(sRow[0].cells[0].innerHTML.toString()));
    $('#ItemID').val($.trim(sRow[0].cells[1].innerHTML.toString()));
    $('#Unit').val($.trim(sRow[0].cells[2].innerHTML.toString()));
    $('#Price').val($.trim(sRow[0].cells[3].innerHTML.toString()));
    $('#Total').val($.trim(sRow[0].cells[4].innerHTML.toString()));
    $('.tbl').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(sRow[0]);
} //End DeleteRow()
$(document).ready(function () {
    // here i have used datatables.js (jQuery Data Table)
    $('.tbl').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [],
            "sRowSelect": "single"
        },
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false
    });
    $('#SalesDateTime').datepicker();
    var oTable = $('.tbl').dataTable();
});  //End Ready Function()

function Add() {
    // Adding item to table
    $('.tbl').dataTable().fnAddData([$('#ItemSalesID').val(), $('#ItemID').val(), $('#Unit').val(), $('#Price').val(), $('#Total').val()]);
    // Making Editable text empty
    $('#ItemSalesID').val("")
    $('#ItemID').val("")
    $('#Price').val("")
    $('#Unit').val("")
    $('#Total').val("")
} //End Add()
function Sales_save() {
    // Step 1: Read View Data and Create JSON Object
    // Creating SalesItem Json Object
    var salesitem = { "SalesID": "", "ItemSalesID": "", "ItemID": "", "Unit": "", "Price": "", "Total": "" };
    // Creating Sales Json Object
    var sales = { "SalesID": "", "SalesNo": "", "SalesDateTime": "", "SalesTotal": "", "SalesPaid": "", "SalesChange": "", "SalesItem": [] };
    // Set Sales Value
    sales.SalesID = $("#SalesID").val();
    sales.SalesNo = $("#SalesNo").val();
    sales.SalesDateTime = $("#SalesDateTime").val();
    sales.SalesTotal = $("#SalesTotal").val();
    sales.SalesPaid = $("#SalesPaid").val();
    sales.SalesChange = $("#SalesChange").val();
    // Getting Table Data from where we will fetch Sales Item Record
    var oTable = $('.tbl').dataTable().fnGetData();
    for (var i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++) {
        // IF This view is for edit then it will read SalesID from Hidden field
        if ($('h2').text() == "Edit") {
            salesitem.SalesID = $('#SalesID').val();
        }
        else {
            salesitem.SalesID = 0;
        }
        // Set SalesItem individual Value
        salesitem.ItemSalesID = oTable[i][0];
        salesitem.ItemID = oTable[i][1];
        salesitem.Unit = oTable[i][2];
        salesitem.Price = oTable[i][3];
        salesitem.Total = oTable[i][4];
        // adding to Sales.SalesItem List Item
        sales.SalesItem.push(salesitem);
        salesitem = { "ItemSalesID": "", "ItemID": "", "Unit": "", "Price": "", "Total": "" };
    }
    // Step 1: Ends Here
    // Set 2: Ajax Post
    // Here i have used ajax post for saving/updating information
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:1221/Sales/Create",
        data: JSON.stringify(sales),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success == "1") {
                window.location.href = "/Sales/Index";
            }
            else {
                alert(result.ex);
            }
        }
    }
    );
}**
</script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Sales</legend>

    <%if (Model != null)
    {%>
         <input type="text" id = "SalesID" name ="SalesID" value = "<%: @Model.SalesID %>" readonly="readonly" />
    <%}%>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesNo) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.SalesNo) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalesNo) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesDateTime) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.SalesDateTime) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalesDateTime) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesTotal) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.SalesTotal) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalesTotal) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesPaid) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.SalesPaid) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalesPaid) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesChange) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.SalesChange) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalesChange) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Item</legend>

        <label>Item Sales ID :</label>
            <%: Html.TextBox("ItemSalesID") %>
        <label>Item ID :</label>
            <%: Html.TextBox("ItemID") %>
        <label>Price :</label>
            <%: Html.TextBox("Price") %>
        <label>Unit :</label>
            <%: Html.TextBox("Unit") %>
        <label>Total :</label>
            <%: Html.TextBox("Total") %>
        **<input type="button" value= "Add Row" onclick="Add()" />**
        <br />
        <br />
        <table class="tbl" id="tbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item Sales ID</th> 
                    <th>Item ID</th> 
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%if (Model != null)
                {%>

                    <% foreach (var item in Model.SalesItem)
                    { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%: Html.DisplayTextFor(i => item.ItemSalesID) %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%: Html.DisplayTextFor(i => item.ItemID) %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%: Html.DisplayTextFor(i => item.Unit) %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%: Html.DisplayTextFor(i => item.Price) %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%: Html.DisplayTextFor(i => item.Total) %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% } %>
                <%}%>
                <%else
                {%>
                <%}%>
            </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
        **<input type="button" value="Delete Selected Row" onclick="DeleteRow()" />**
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <p>
        **<input type="button" value="Sales Save" onclick="Sales_save()" />**
    </p>
</fieldset>
<% } %>

<div>
<%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptsSection" runat="server">
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") %>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.8.1/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.8.1/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.8.1/extras/TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js") %>"type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables-1.8.1/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables-1.8.1/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools_JUI.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you haven't closed the import tag `<script type = "text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" >` with `</script>`.

You then need to add a new script tag for your own script `<script type="text/javascript">`